# How can I make a ksoap2 call in async task?

Tags: android, .net, web-services, android-asynctask, ksoap2

I am a newbie on android development. I am trying to develop an application which will connect with .net webservice in order to retrieve data. I would like to make the *ksoap2* call with `AsyncTask`. How I call it *asyncronus* with asynctask?

My SoapCall class is

```
public class SoapCall {

public final static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.alpha.net.com/ExecuteEBSCommand";

public final static String OPERATION_NAME = "ExecuteEBSCommand";

public final static String NAMESPACE = "http://www.alpha.net.com";

public final static String URL = "http://192.168.2.100/Ebs2Alpha/Service.asmx";





public String connection(String Command, String CommandParameters) throws Throwable, Throwable {
    String response = null;
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);
    Request.addProperty("strCommand", Command);
    Request.addProperty("strCommandParameters", CommandParameters);



    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
    // Needed to make the internet call

    // Allow for debugging - needed to output the request

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;

        response = result.getProperty(0).toString();


    return response;
    }
}
```

So far I am getting the response by calling the connection method in main activity with

```
SoapCall  call1= new SoapCall();

call1.connection("get_clients", "%");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `AsyncTask` is straightforward. Here is an example.

```
 public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String response = null;
    SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);
    Request.addProperty("strCommand", params[0]);
    Request.addProperty("strCommandParameters", params[1]);



    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
    // Needed to make the internet call

    // Allow for debugging - needed to output the request

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
    // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;

    response = result.getProperty(0).toString();


    return response;
  }
}
```

And the call to the task with parameters.

```
MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
myTask.execute(new String[] {Command, CommandParameters});
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use the AsyncTaskLoader which for my taste is easier than the AsyncTask. 
Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html), the example is very extensive and looks intimidating at first, you'll probably find much simpler ones. The idea is that your Activity implements `LoaderCallbacks` for the creation of the loader and a method that is being called when the loader has finished. You 'start' a loader via the `LoaderManager`. 
The AsynctaskLoader is a class that `extends AsyncTaskLoader` and does the asynchronous stuff.

I'll give you a simple example:

This is the AsyncTaskLoader:

```
public class StartupLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Boolean> {

Context context;

public StartupLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    forceLoad();

}

@Override
public Boolean loadInBackground() {

    // DO STUFF!

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onStopLoading() {

}

@Override
public void onCanceled(Boolean data) {
    super.onCanceled(data);

}

@Override
protected void onReset() {
    super.onReset();



}

}
```

This is what you have in the Activity that will start the loader, it is an inner class:

```
public class StartupCallback implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Boolean> loader, Boolean succ) {

        // Here you get your results back

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Boolean> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        return new StartupLoader(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Boolean> loader) {

    }
}
```

And this is how you start the loader from whereever you want (within that Activity):

```
StartupCallback startupCallback = new StartupCallback();
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, startupCallback);
```

where 0 is an ID that you give the loader, null is a Bundle of arguments. 
Good luck :)