# i recieve an java.io.EOFeception error while using Soap protocol

Tags: android, soap

i made a client(android)-server(PHP) system that client just Login (multiple time, it is not an actual Login) in the server. when i click login button , everything is just cool and correct and a welcome message will be received, but when i try to click Login button again i see "java.io.EOFEception" error, and when i try to click the button for Third time, it is just correct again and after that again error and so on..., i think the problem is with my connection that it is not closed yet. what should i do ? here is my Login button codes:

```
      logi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_2);

               //SoapObject 
               request.addProperty("email", "xxxx@yahoo.com");
               request.addProperty("password", "1234");
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

              HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

              try
              {
                httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_2, envelope);
                Object response = envelope.getResponse();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),exception.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: no one to answer me, help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe you have a connection problem.  I believe this could be a problem on your main thread. Regardless, you need to put your request inside of an AsyncTask.  This allows android to make the call on a new background thread which became required for all HTTP calls after Honeycomb.   I believe this link provides a good example of the implementation. [How can I make a ksoap2 call in async task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483717/how-can-i-make-a-ksoap2-call-in-async-task)