# Android Button onClick run method, Unfortunately App has stopped

Tags: java, php, android

I'm trying to post data to external PHP file, i have a button and when i click on it, it should run the method and post the data to the php file then return some data and print it.

In **activity_main.xml** :

```
<Button
        android:onClick="postData" />
```

In **MainActivity.java** :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void postData(String toPost) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("__the_php_file.php");

        String MyName = "Amr";

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", MyName));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

            String reverseString = response;
            Toast.makeText(this, "response" + reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "CPE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when i click the button it gives me this error : `Unfortunately App has stopped`

why isn't this code working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you want,i think you will find it useful

http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/

Comment: This eis exactly what i'm looking for, you saved my project! but now i've tested everything and it's working but what if i'm using this link example and i want to get response from the php file not just posting to it? if i didn't connect to the internet and click submit the app stop working what if i want just print a toast message e.g says please connect to internet! i'm really happy cuz your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your method from

```
public void postData(String toPost) {
```

to

```
public void postData(View v) {...}
```

You should pass **View** as a argument of you `onClick()` method.

Comment: Changed to (View v) and still getting the same error! i think the error in the method but i cannot find where is it!

Comment: what is your logcat?

Comment: I Cannot use Emulator i'm testing on my Phone so how to know the logCat?

Answer (score 2):

See here:

[android:onClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) method name which passing to `onClick` attribute *must be public and accept a View as its only parameter*

means method must be like :

```
public void postData(View view) {
  ....
}
```

Second important point in current implementation is calling `HttpClient.execute` on UI Thread which probably cause :

[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) Exception.

To avoid this Exception use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to make api request in background Thread

Comment: If we will do something like this idea with AsyncTask so what is the best and short code example to do that? sorry for being annoying but i'll appreciate your help alot!

Comment: @AmrSubZero: see this [Understanding AsyncTask – Once and Forever](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/) easy example

Answer (score 1):

```
public void methodName(final View view) {
// Do your tasks here
}
```

You should change your code to send network operations .

**Network operations must be done in background**.

Otherwise you will get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

[Example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/09/android-asynctask-httpclient-with.html)

Comment: Yes, but still getting the same error!

Comment: Please post your LogCat outputs

Comment: I'm installing the .apk on my phone and testing it cuz i cannot run emulator for some reasons! so what now?

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask to send to php file and print it on onPreexecute

Comment: Can you please explain more/give example?

Answer (score 1):

Refers this link for Ksoap2 and Async Task.
[How can I make a ksoap2 call in async task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483717/how-can-i-make-a-ksoap2-call-in-async-task)

**Not forgot to import Ksoap2.jar file and give internet permission in AndroidManifest file.**